# Recurring contribution (monthly) with 'Pay Later'

Tags: recurring-contributions

Using 5.24.6 on Drupal - I have a contribution page for donations with the possibility to 'pay later' (bank transfer) or to pay by credit card (PayPal), and the possibility for choosing monthly payments (Recurring contribution).
When a user chooses both monthly and pay later, they get the error 'You cannot set up a recurring contribution if you are not paying online by credit card.'

How can I allow people to 'declare' that they intend to make a monthly donation by bank transfer?

Comment: Unfortunately afaik there is no core function that allows users to "'declare' that they intend to make a monthly donation by bank transfer" using a contribution page. Pledges may be a way to do that in the backend and you could create a custom form. In general bank transfer workflows are not as deeply integrated with CiviCRM as other means of payment and/or you may have to use  a number of extensions to support your work.

Comment: This is not entirely accurate - it is possible  with iATS Payments Extension and it’s in the making for Stripe Extension -> I've posted a screenshot!

Answer (score 3):

This extension solves your use case and was designed for that purpose and several other related ones:

https://github.com/adixon/ca.civicrm.contributionrecur

For example, you can track recurring offline payments (whether by bank transfer or other form of recurring payments that don't have a civi extension) by configuring it to auto-generate contributions for those offline payments. Then you just have a monthly reconciliation task to weed out the ones that didn't go through.

It supports both credit card and bank transfer offline recurring payments (using separate 'placeholder' type payment processors).

Comment: Good to know about this. I haven't been certain in past if best way to do this was by using Pledges - looks like this avoids that

Comment: It probably depends on the details. This extension automates a lot, which may or may not be what you want. If you want to be certain about your income in the system, then importing the contributions each month is more reliable, but if you just want to keep track automatically of a whole slew of reliable monthly contributions, then this might be what you want.

Comment: Is it also compatible with 5.24.6?

Comment: I installed it, Amounts tab says 'Recurring Contributions' = true, and Recurring tab says 'Force recurring-only on this page if available' = yes.
Still, when I choose the 'Pay Later' option, it says - 'You cannot set up a recurring contribution if you are not paying online by credit card.'

Comment: This extension has quite a few features, as per the documentation. For the feature you want, you have to set up the "offline credit card" payment processor. The two items you encountered are a different feature.

Comment: I set up an offline processor, and it works, but when selected it asks for many mandatory billing address fields. is there a way to disable that? i have my profile already and don't want any other fields added.

Comment: Yes, but you'd have to edit the code. But I'd recommend you don't - remove the duplicate fields from your profiles instead.

Answer (score 2):

That error message is misleading! Payment Processors which implement Direct Debit can do recurring Contributions. iATS Payments extension (both legacy and 1stPay) implement recurring ACH. In addition there is a make it happen for Stripe extension that’s well on it’s way to get ACH implemented.

Here's a screenshot of a monthly donation by bank transfer - this is a CiviCRM native Contribution page.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have [Offline recurring extension](https://github.com/pradpnayak/uk.co.circleinteractive.offlinerecurring/tree/UpgradeExtension) forked into my github account that supports for latest version of Civi. This extension allows one to create Contribution recur offline for check/cash payments/bank transfer etc. I think the same extension can also be supported to capture online pay later recurring contribution.